# Create proper link from MVC5 Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an mvc view that contains a table of data. I want to include a 'Remove' button in there so users can delete records. I'm having trouble generating the proper link to go to my Delete action. In order to delete i need two values from the table, not just an id.

```
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
   "DeleteWorkItem", 
   "Project/Work",
   new { hId = @w.ProjectId, workId = @w.WorkId},
   new AjaxOptions()
    {
        AllowCache = false,
        HttpMethod = "DELETE",
        Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
    })
</td>
```

is what i have so far but when the link is clicked it creates a Get request to a url and appends the two parameters in the query string. How can i get those parameter values in the url instead of the query string. Also, I want to call the http delete method but no matter what i put in that options value i get a get
My WorkController

```
        [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult DeleteWorkItem(int hId, int workId)
    {
        this.brWorkManager.Delete(forhealthId, workId);

        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
```

my route:

```
           routes.MapRoute(
         "WorkItemDelete",
         "FHProject/Work/DeleteWorkItem",
         new { controller = "Work", action = "DeleteWorkItem" },
         new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("DELETE") }
         );
```

Comment: I assume you mean as route values? Have you defined a specific route for  `DeleteWorkItem` with placeholders for `{hId}/{workId}`? But a delete method should not be a GET anyway (your changing data so it should be a POST

Comment: I do that that route defined. but i can tell from the url the params are going query string and not as route values. shouldn't a delete be a DELETE?

Comment: Just noticed you already have `HttpMethod = "POST"` Can you show the route definition and a sample of the url thats being created.

Comment: Your url in the route definition needs to be `"FHProject/Work/DeleteWorkItem/{hId}/{workId}"` which will then generate something like `FHProject/Work/DeleteWorkItem/2/6` depending on the values of `hId` and `workId`

Comment: have tried that. and many other permutations. but it is the link going out that always has the query string and is always a Get regardless of all else. that's the frustrating part.

Comment: I dont understand why you using `Ajax.ActionLink()` if you want a POST - you should be using a form and submitting it

Comment: i'm using ajax because i want a delete, not a post. because i am trying to delete a record.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835450/use-delete-form-method-in-html-beginform). But you have `return RedirectToAction("Details");` in your method which will never happen because ajax calls will never redirect.

Comment: in the end i wound up just going with a post. I couldn't get the delete override to work and get the params right together. but i'm happy with what i have now. thanks