# Deleting an object from index page while staying on the same page (MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show a list of items in MVC with a delete actionlink next to them. If an user wishes to deletes the item, he simply clickes it and the following action will take place: 
-> item get's deleted 
-> page get's refreshed

What actually happens is the following: 
-> items are viewed correctly

What happens when delete gets clicked? 
-> The link changes to /Home/Index/1 (going to the correct method (delete)
-> Page doesn't refreshes, item doesn't get removed but loads again really fast and link stays /Home/Index/1

### Code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Flight> Flights = db.Flights.ToList();

        return View(Vluchten);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Flight flight = db.Flights.Find(id);
        db.Flights.Remove(flight);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Index");
    }
```

View Code:

```
//Items are shown and this is the last <td>:
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Index", new { id=item.Id })
```

Where does my problem seem to be situated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Delete method is looking for a POST, an ActionLink does a GET. To simplify this just change your method signature:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ... do all the things ...

    return RedirectToAction("Index","Index");
}
```

and then your ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete", new { id=item.Id })
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't think about the POST/GET thing! thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be making changes to the server from a GET.  GET is supposed to be Idempotent.  You should be creating a a form around each and at least performing at POST, but you should be using a Delete to be semantically correct.  like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835450/use-delete-form-method-in-html-beginform  
one problem with performing a delete it with a GET is if a this is out on the internet and a crawler hits your page, it will delete everything in the table.

Comment: Do not do this. Use a `@Html.BeginForm()` (add the ID as a route value) and a submit button to do a POST.

Comment: The context of this Q is about routing. Changing/deleting data in GET vs POST is for another time/place/question.